# jQuery - Remember triggered function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar for languages.
You can hide it with a jQuery button.
But every time you refresh the page, the navbar appears again.

How could I make it keep hidden once you click the 'Hide' button, 
until you click the button again to show it.

*I've already got the function for hiding and showing.*

### jQuery:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#lang').toggle('show');
            debugger
            if($('#hideshow').text()=="Hide"){
                $('#hideshow').text("Show")
                }
        });
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HX48L/1/)** 
*(The fiddle doesn't look too good, but works)*

By the way, I'm really new to JS and jQuery! :)

Comment: To remember the state of the bar on reload, I would use a cookie.  Have you considered that?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But I'm very new to JavaScript so none of the cookie-tutorials were really good for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a persistent state of your bar, you need to store this state in either a cookie or in local storage. You could use for example:

- http://www.jstorage.info/
- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie (tutorial at http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use cookie.

```
// if you want to set it for num of days, pass that in. 
// Otherwise leave empty and it will be a session cookie.
// and remember to pass in a number for days, not a string
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
   var date, expires;
   if (days) {
      date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }else{
      expires = "";
   }
   document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

If you want to read the cookie, include the following method.

```
function getCookie(name) {
   var i, c, arr, cName = name + "=";
    arr = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(i=0;i < arr.length;i++) {
       c = arr[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
             c = c.substring(1,c.length);
          }
         if (c.indexOf(cName) == 0) {
            return c.substring(cName.length,c.length);
         }
    }
return '';
}
```

To get and write to the cookie, do:

```
setCookie('naviSet', true);
```

To read the cookie 'naviSet: // you can name it anything you want.

```
getCookie('naviSet')
```

Then in your code, test to see if it is set.. if not, run your code THEN set it.

```
if( getCookie('naviSet') != true){
   // run your code
   // set your coookie, to whatever value you want. I just happend to use "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use [COOKIE plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/):

Set a cookie

```
$.cookie("div_status", "hide"); //set hide or show
```

Get a cookie

```
alert( $.cookie("div_status") ); //then call on page load to get div status
```

Delete the cookie

```
$.removeCookie("div_status"); //remove if not need
```